# Do a research in a Firestore document

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

In my collection "users", each user is defined by their name, list of hobbies, and skills:

Structure of a document in "users":

```
name : "Name"
hobbies: ["hobby1","hobby2","hobby3"]
skills: ["skill1","skill2","skill3"]
```

What I want is: Get all documents in the collection where one of those fields contains a specific word. The problem is that currently I get all documents and then I do a loop to retain the matching documents. But I would prefer to do a query instead (reads are expensive). So I was thinking to reorganize the document like this:

New structure:

```
data: ["Name","hobby1","hobby2","hobby3",skill1","skill2","skill3"]
```

So I could do a query with "where" and "array-contains". What do you think? Isn't it strange?

Comment: What is the exact specific query you need to perform? Please edit your question and add an example.

Comment: I have a search bar. When the user types "football", I want to display all documents where football is in hobbies or skills. With the second structure above, I can do: users.where("data", arrayContains: "football");

Comment: So as per my understanding, you got what you need, right?

Comment: yes but my document is loosing organization

Comment: So you need to create a multiple `array-contains` query?

Comment: Or, can I keep the first structure and create a new field "data" where I duplicate name, skills and hobbies ?

Comment: I didn't think about multiple query. You think is the best choice ?

Comment: What is the exact query that you're looking for? 1. `users.where("hobbies", arrayContains: "hobby1");?` 2. `skills.where("data", arrayContains: "skill1");?` 3. Or an `OR` operation between them? 4. Or an `AND` operation between them?

Comment: `users.where("hobbies", arrayContains: "word")`. If none document is returned, I try `users.where("skills", arrayContains: "word")` (and again for the name)

Comment: One more quick question. So you basically need a successive search, right? First, you need to search the `hobbies` array for a particular word, and if you don't get a result, you perform another search, in the `skills` array, for another word, and if again you don't get a result, you search for the name. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct but I use the same particular word

Comment: So for each successive search, you need to use the **exact** same word, correct?

Comment: yes you're right

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a **`OR`** statement between the *hobbies* and *skills* then you can't use a query that uses `array-contains`. As stated on this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership:%7E:text=results%20only%20once.-,You%20can%20use%20at%20most%20one%20array%2Dcontains%20clause%20per%20query.%20You%20can%27t%20combine%20array%2Dcontains%20with%20array%2Dcontains%2Dany.,-in%2C%20not):

> You can use at most one array-contains clause per query. You can't combine array-contains with array-contains-any.

What I would suggest is to combine the skills and hobbies into one.:
e.g.:

```
name : "Name"
skillsandhobbies : ["Hobby1", "Hobby2", "Hobby3", "Skill1", "Skill2", "Skill3"]
```

Then you can use this sample query to get all the documents that have hobbies or skills that contain a specific word:

```
const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("skillsandhobbies", "array-contains", "specific-word"));
```

Comment: So that's what I was thinking, but why don't you let the name inside ?

Comment: That's for best practice. If there's an instance that you just need only a specific field which is for e.g. `name` then you don't even need to fetch for other fields. and also, to add, if you want to establish your Firestore Security Rules that needs a specific field that you want to validate then you want to really specify and indicate the field you want to compare to.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood from your comments, you basically need to perform a successive search. You need to search the hobbies `array` for a particular word, and if you don't get any results, you need to perform another search, in the `skills` array, for the **exact** same word, and if again you don't get any results, you need to search for the name.

Since you didn't specify a particular programming language, I assume you're using Flutter, as in the other questions of yours. So I will try to explain real quickly how to do it.

First, you need to create the following query:

```
final queryHobbiesByWord = users.where("hobbies", arrayContains: "word");
```

Then you have to call `get()`. As soon as you get a successful callback, you have to check if the number of documents that exist inside the QuerySnapshot is greater than zero. If it is, then perform the logic you want, otherwise, inside the callback create another query that looks like this:

```
final querySkillsByWord = users.where("skills", arrayContains: "word");
```

Do the exact same thing as about. If the number of documents that exist inside the QuerySnapshot is greater than zero, then perform the logic you want, otherwise, inside the callback create another query that looks like this:

```
final queryNameByWord = users.where("name", isEqualTo: "word");
```

Again, perform the same operation as above, and that's pretty much it. Don't forget to perform each operation inside the callback of the previous one.

Comment: Allright, thank you for your efforts

Comment: You're very welcome, Jordaninho. Give it a try, and tel me if it woks.

Comment: Hey Jordaninho. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: I didn't because I will need it later, but there's no reason to not work

Comment: Please confirm when you got it working.

Comment: Hey Jordaninho. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Are you just waiting for me to close the thread ?

Comment: Only if it helped. If not, maybe I can help you with other information, so you can solve that and go ahead with your project.

Comment: I will not implement the solution in the near future. I keep the thread open to see other alternatives.